# На основе таблице построить другую

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Я хочу сгруппировать данные в таблице по определнному признаку.
Например у меня есть таблица **order** с полями

- id (int)
- name (str)
- region (int)

и мне надо получить таблицу вида

- region (int)
- [order]

Я конечно могу получить все кортежи **order** и уже в питоне обработать, но может можно как-то через sql это сделать. Даже незнаю как такое гуглить. Буду рад любой информации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что нужно получить в результате, но возможно вам подойдет фунция PostgreSQL **ARRAY_AGG()**

Т.е. в вашем случае запрос может быть вида

```
SELECT region, ARRAY_AGG(id) AS order_ids FROM "order" GROUP BY region
```

В результате у вас в первом столбец будет идентификатор региона, а во втором массив из id заказов сделанных в этом регионе.

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, спасибо)